# removelastobject method is making my app crash

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have this: `NSMutableArray *myMArray` and I have 2 `IBaction`, `(insert)` & `(remove)`. I have worked out everything so when the user hits `(insert)` an object, it will be inserted to `myMarray`. My `(remove)` action has `[myMArray removeLastObject]`.

My problem, which should be obvious now, is that when I insert lets say 5 objects, by hitting `(insert)` 5 times and then hitting `(remove)` 6 times , the thing will crash because the array is empty.

I understand what the problem is, but can’t find a solution to implement when the user hits `(remove)` and the index in `myMArray` is at 0 to stop the app from crashing.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the array size before calling `removeLastObject` on it.

```
if ( [myMArray count] > 0 ) {
    [myMArray removeLastObject];
}
```

Comment: cheers m8, i knew i should use the if statment but didn't know what to write in the comparison, appreciate it